# Purpose of byte type in Java

Tags: java, byte, primitive

I read this line in the Java tutorial:

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive). The
>   byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where
>   the memory savings actually matters. **They can also be used in place of
>   int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a
>   variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.**

I don't clearly understand the bold line. Can somebody explain it for me?

Comment: I've gave an answer, but whoever wrote this tutorial, in my opinion it's just BS. Nobody should fool themselves by thinking it's a proper form of documentation.

Comment: I don't think they mean it as a replacement for actual documentation. They're probably saying that by reading byte, you automatically think of the scope of the values, unlike int where the range is so big you just think number.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Byte has a (signed) range from -128 to 127, where as int has a (also signed) range of −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

What it means is that since the values you're going to use will always be between that range, by using the byte type you're telling anyone reading your code this value will be at most between -128 to 127 always without having to document about it.

Still, proper documentation is always key and you should only use it in the case specified for readability purposes, not as a replacement for documentation.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using a variable which maximum value is 127 you can use `byte` instead of `int` so others know without reading any `if` conditions after, which may check the boundaries, that this variable can only have a value between -128 and 127.

So it's kind of self-documenting code - as mentioned in the text you're citing.

Personally, I do not recommend this kind of "documentation" - only because a variable can only hold a maximum value of 127 doesn't reveal it's really purpose.

Answer (score 6):

I imagine one can use `byte` for anything dealing with *actual* bytes.

Also, the parts (red, green and blue) of colors commonly have a range of 0-255 (although `byte` is technically -128 to 127, but that's the same amount of numbers).

There may also be other uses.

The general opposition I have to using `byte` (and probably why it isn't seen as often as it can be) is that there's lots of casting needed. For example, whenever you do arithmetic operations on a `byte` (except `X=`), it is automatically promoted to `int` (even `byte+byte`), so you have to cast it if you want to put it back into a `byte`.

**A very elementary example:**

[FileInputStream::read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) returns a `byte` wrapped in an `int` (or -1). This can be cast to an `byte` to make it clearer. **I'm not supporting this example as such** (because I don't really (at this moment) see the point of doing the below), just saying something similar may make sense.

It could also have *returned* a byte in the first place (and possibly thrown an exception if end-of-file). This may have been even clearer, but the way it was done does make sense.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("Somefile.txt");
int val;
while ((val = file.read()) != -1)
{
  byte b = (byte)val;
  // ...
}
```

If you don't know much about `FileInputStream`, you may not know what `read` returns, so you see an `int` and you may assume the valid range is the entire range of `int` (-2^31 to 2^31-1), or possibly the range of a `char` (0-65535) (not a bad assumption for file operations), but then you see the cast to `byte` and you give that a second thought.

If the return type were to have been `byte`, you would know the valid range from the start.

**Another example:**

One of [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)'s constructors could have been changed from 3 `int`'s to 3 `byte`'s instead, since their range is limited to 0-255.

Comment: This is confusing and completely out of context as to what OP asked.

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon It's making clear that `read` returns a `byte` wrapped in an `int`.

Comment: That's now that the document he posted means though. And why wouldn't you just make val a byte and then cast it to int when finished, making it more obvious that you're working with bytes (or at least are only interested in the byte part, which casting also does).

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon `FileInputStream::read` returns an `int`. A return value of `-1` indicates the end of the file - this information will be lost if you cast it to `byte` right away (since `255` is also a valid return value, which becomes `-1` when cast to `int`), you need to do the `-1` check *before* casting to byte.

Comment: @Duckeling: your answer is a little bit confusing but I understand your point

Answer (score 6):

`Integers` in Java are stored in 32 bits; `bytes` are stored in 8 bits.

Let's say you have an array with one million entries. Yikes! That's huge!

```
int[] foo = new int[1000000];
```

Now, for each of these integers in `foo`, you use **32 bits** or **4 bytes** of memory. In total, that's **4 million bytes**, or **4MB**.

Remember that an `integer` in Java is a whole number between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 inclusively. What if your array `foo` only needs to contain whole numbers between, say, 1 and 100? That's a whole lot of numbers you aren't using, by declaring `foo` as an `int` array.

This is when `byte` becomes helpful. `Bytes` store whole numbers between -128 and 127 inclusively, which is perfect for what you need! But why choose `bytes`? *Because they use one-fourth of the space of integers*. Now your array is wasting less memory:

```
byte[] foo = new byte[1000000];
```

Now each entry in `foo` takes up **8 bits** or **1 byte** of memory, so in total, `foo` takes up only **1 million bytes** or **1MB** of memory.

That's a *huge* improvement over using `int[]` - you just saved 3MB of memory.

Clearly, you wouldn't want to use this for arrays that hold numbers that would exceed 127, so another way of reading the bold line you mentioned is, **Since bytes are limited in range, this lets developers know that the variable is strictly limited to these bounds**. There is no reason for a developer to assume that a number stored as a byte would ever exceed 127 or be less than -128. Using appropriate data types saves space and informs other developers of the limitations imposed on the variable.

Comment: Just saying - most of your answer focusses on "saving memory", which was *not* in bold.

Answer (score 1):

It means that knowing that a value is explicitly declared as a very small number might help you recall the purpose of it.

Go for real docs when you have to create a documentation for your code, though, relying on datatypes is not documentation.

Answer (score 0):

An int covers the values from 0 to 4294967295 or 2 to the 32nd power. This is a huge range and if you are scoring a test that is out of 100 then you are wasting that extra spacce if all of your numbers are between 0 and 100. It just takes more memory and harddisk space to store ints, and in serious data driven applications this translates to money wasted if you are not using the extra range that ints provide.

Comment: Correction: An int covers the values from -2147483648 to 2147483647. [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Also, you're just dealing with the "saving space" part, which was *not* in bold.

Comment: [Java doesn't have unsigned types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java).

Comment: Oh, actually `char` is unsigned, and basically `boolean`, see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

byte data types are generally used when you want to handle data in the forms of streams either from file or from network. Reason behind this is because network and files works on the concept of byte.

Example: FileOutStream always takes byte array as input parameter.