Java Integers Memory Usage
I have been learning Java recently at w3schools and came to a part related to saving memory as shown in the image so I was wondering if they meant by memory the rams or the storage, thanks!
question showcasing image
I know this is a very silly question but I like learning everything in details (:
About my tries...
I tried nothing, since I am not sure of what I exactly search for XD

can you  please read and consider the answer of Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? ||| What do you understand as "rams" and as "storage"? What's the difference (for you)?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194681/purpose-of-byte-type-in-java, it's almost always RAM unless it's serialized raw, which is rare since it's more common to either use human-readable serialization or just database. Well technically the OS might use a storage-backed swap too.

Read [ask] and try not to post images of text. For learning Java, I recommend this tutorial.

https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-xdygvn/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/93/4518/815101-B21__26797.1667966090.png?c=2&imbypass=on

A byte value and an int value in Java exist in memory (RAM). The text you quote refers to that. These types are defined by the Java specifications.
Such values can be written out to storage. How much space they take in storage depends on how you write them. That is not part of the Java specifications.

By the way, the supposedly smaller types do not always reduce memory usage. Furthermore, they can result in slower math operations in some cases. See this Question for more info. Generally best to make a habit of using int rather than byte and short until you have (a) identified and proven a need to optimize and (b) determined that the smaller type makes an actual difference.

To expand on the answer: The "smaller types" do not have corresponding types in the bytecode, thus a byte (boolean, and short) is represented as int in bytecde. There are, however, specialized types for the corresponding arrays. So there is a size-difference between a byte[] and an int[].
