# Are byte arrays initialised to zero in Java?

Tags: java

In the following line, can `buffer` be assumed to be filled with zeroes?

```
byte buffer[] = new byte[120];
```

Comment: This only takes 10 sec to test yourself...

Comment: @AppX For instance in C, this would work _sometimes_ depending on compiler and lucky memory allocation. I didn't know whether it was the same for Java.

Comment: @AppX But then you don't know if it only applies in your environment or is consistent over all the different ones and won't change over time.

Comment: Java is much more system independant than C, unless you're doing something crazy it will be the same on all systems. cc @AngeloNeuschitzer

Answer (score 13):

Language-lawyer-answer completely based on Java Language Specification:

[10.3. Array Creation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3)

> An array is created by an array creation expression (§15.10) or an array initializer (§10.6).

[10.6. Array initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

> *ArrayInitializer*:
>
> { *VariableInitializers*<sub>opt ,opt</sub> }

So, we can conclude that your expression *is not* an array initializer (it isn't wrapped in braces). So we move to array creation:

[15.10.1 Run-Time Evaluation of Array Creation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)

> ...Then, if a single DimExpr appears, a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and **each component of the array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).**
>
> Otherwise, if n DimExpr expressions appear, then array creation effectively executes a set of nested loops of depth n-1 to create the implied arrays of arrays.

And finally:

[4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> ...For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (byte)0.

So the answer is **Yes** any implementation of java is expected to initialize byte array with zeroes.

Answer (score 10):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

The default value of a `byte` is 0.

[image]

Comment: That's only part of the answer.

Answer (score 8):

All objects and arrays are initialised with zeros or the equivalent (null, false) on construction.

The default values are listed in [JLS 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) and thus are guaranteed.

---

FROM 4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables

Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10):

- For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
  (byte)0.
- For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of
  (short)0.
- For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
- For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
- For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
- For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
- For type char, the default value is the null character, that is,
  '\u0000'.
- For type boolean, the default value is false.
- For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

Comment: Local object references are not initialized with null on construction.        {Byte b; System.out.print(b);}   Will not compile since b is a local variable and not a field

Comment: @RonE Could you expand, please? Would using `byte b` solve that?

Comment: IMHO, Local variables are not constructed.  There is no `new` for a local variable. ;)

Comment: @Andreas No, the compiler checks all local variables to ensure they have an initial value before being used.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Consider `byte buffer[] = new byte[120]; int num_bytes = myInputStream.read(buffer, 0, 120);` . What about the bytes in `buffer` after `num_bytes`? How have they been initialised?

Comment: @Andreas They have been initialised before the read, even if they didn't need to be. See the quote from the JLS I have added. ;)

Answer (score -2):

Why you didn't try this one.

```
       byte buffer[] = new byte[120];
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(buffer[i]);
        }
```

Please find the reference

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Because there's no way of testing whether it's _guaranteed_. What if I were just lucky with memory allocation?

Comment: This is not an answer. There is nothing here or in the link that answers the question. It should have been posted as a comment.