# Simple Conversion from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++

I am tasked with porting this C++ code over to Java.  I am much better with Java than I am with C++.  I understand bit-shifting to a large extent, but I don't really understand what the unsigned long value is doing in this context.

What would this look like in Java?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   short netSpeed = 3;    
   cout << "netSpeed before: " << netSpeed << endl;

   netSpeed = 1UL << netSpeed;
   cout << "netSpeed after: " << netSpeed << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run it and check what it does...?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java

Comment: you are much better with java than c++ but you don't know how to print to the console? do you see the contradiciton

Comment: Of course I ran it.  Did you read my question?  I was wondering about the 1UL.\

Comment: You're doing bit shifting so this doesn't matter here, but if you start playing at the byte level The Big Weird will probably be Java always exposes big endian and C++ will be platform dependent endian. If numbers read back insane values, check the endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ developer is not taking any chances with a platform's representation of an signed integral type, which could be 1's or 2's complement. They are also guarding themselves against undefined behaviour due to overflow of the integral value 1 which could be as small as a 16 bit `int`.

Using a 1UL is giving them reassurance that the result of the shift will be 0b1000. `UL` is forcing the compiler to use an `unsigned long` type.

Actually it's superfluous in this case, and given that Java *always* uses 2's complement for integral types (and they are all signed, aside from the `char` type), it's perfectly safe for you to write `1 << netSpeed` in your Java port.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy that. The resulting value (1 << 3) is 8, which is guaranteed to be representable by `int` in C++, so I'm not sure what kind of chances the developer isn't taking.

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing before by less than confident C++ developers. I do state (perhaps not clearly enough) that it's superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

This is the exact conversion of your code from C++ to Java:

```
class Speed {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       short netSpeed = 3;
       System.out.println("netSpeed before: "+netSpeed);

       netSpeed = (short) (1 << netSpeed);
       System.out.println("netSpeed after: "+netSpeed);
    }
}
```