# How to correct convert the int to byte in Android?

Tags: android, byte

I want to convert the int to byte and put into the byte array like the following code:

```
    private int StartByte       = 0xF1;
    private int GetProductInfo  = 0xA0;
    private int NoDataByte      = 0xFF;
    private int EndByte         = 0xED;

byte[] params = new byte[]{(byte)(StartByte & 0xFF),
                           (byte)(GetProductInfo & 0xFF),
                           (byte)(NoDataByte & 0xFF),
                           (byte)(EndByte & 0xFF)};
```

And I show the content like the following code:

```
for(int i=0 ; i <params.length ; i++){
  Log.d(TAG,"params["+i+"] = " + params[i]);
}
```

The log show like the following:

```
params[0] = -15
params[1] = -96
params[2] = -1
params[3] = -19
```

But the `0xF1` should be `241` not `-15` , and the `0xA0` should be `60` not `-96`
I already do `& 0xFF`.

Did I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you should display the values in the array also hexadecimal. Then you will see that they are still the same.

Comment: And `byte` is not signed or unsigned. Its just eight bits. You can interpret them as you like.

Comment: `I already do & 0xFF.`. On the wrong place. You should do that while displaying the byte values of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using long instead of int.

**EDIT**
***There are no Uints in Java as discussed here: ***
[Declaring an unsigned int in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java)

You will have to use signed values.

Comment: you mean `long`?

Comment: Apologies, C# habits. Yes, I do.. I shall amend my answer.