# Java primitive long overflow

Tags: java, integer-overflow

A C# system is generating data and providing data to another Java system using SBE(Simple Binary Encoding) by primitiveType="uint64" (long).

In Java, when data is received as primitive long it is overflowing and in few cases leading to –ve numbers.

How to handle this situation ?

Comment: ... not sending invalid values?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening, as C#'s `uint64` should be analogous to Java's `long`.  Can you include some data which is causing this problem?

Comment: you can use BigInteger

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Presumably the difference is that `uint64` is unsigned, whereas Java's `long` is signed. So any number in the top half of `uint64`'s range will end up negative when it is interpreted as a `long`.

Comment: If the overflow is happening because of invalid inputs then you could throw an exception if it is causing problems further down the workflow.

Comment: unsigned or signed does not really make a difference, you're just receiving 64 bits of data which you interpret as a number. What are you using this number for?

Comment: If you do arithmetics with that number, then maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java) will help you

Comment: Have you looked at the `xxxUnsigned` methods of `java.lang.Long`? They may help.

Comment: @khelwood Yes you are correct the difference is exactly that uint64 is unsigned, whereas Java's long is signed. I have to store this number in KDB database without any processing as long

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the unsigned long as `long`, as "long" as one does not calculate with the long. You can even display that long as unsigned using `Long.toUnsignedString(n)`.

Otherwise store it in a `BigInteger`. Ideally loaded as 8 big-endian bytes.

```
// Some snippets, unordered, showing useful constructs.
long n = ...;
n = Long.reverseBytes();
byte[] bigendian = new byte[8];
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bigendian); // .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
buf.putLong(n);

// Creating a BigInteger from unsigned long's bytes, requiring big-endian order.
BigInteger num = new BigInteger(1, bigendian); // 1 = positive
```

Comment: Even if you calculate with the `long`, you can usually get away with using methods like [`Long.divideUnsigned()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#divideUnsigned-long-long-). (The other basic arithmetic operations are identical in two's complement.)

Comment: @biziclop Thanks, I almost added `divideUnsigned/remainderUnsigned` myself. I find it remarkable that numbers > 2^63 are actually used.