# How to make Arduino and Java communicate over singed bytes

Tags: java, arduino, byte

I am sending byte[] array to Arduino from java over UART. But in java value above 127 is represented in 2's complement which Arduino is not able to comprehend properly. How to solve this issue?

Comment: in Java `byte` cannot be above 127! The question is not clear at all, maybe some data example **and** code will help

Answer (score 1):

Java's lack of unsigned types is a [know pain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java).
The easiest solution for bytes is to simply use a larger datatype, like `short` or `int`, and cast appropriately:

```
byte b = (byte) 0x80;
System.out.println(b); //prints "-128"
int i = (int) b & 0xff; //casting is optional since 0xff is an int
System.out.println(i); //prints "128"
```

Oh, and if that helps, [Google's Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) has a [nice little class](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.java) for handling unsigned Bytes

If the problem is with sending the bytes, and not receiving them, that's even simpler. If you need to send `0x80`, just send `0x80`. The fact that Java treats it as -128 is not important. You'll still be sending `0x80` over the wire.

Comment: @Matt but I have to send byte[] array over uart . How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the problem you're having with that? Just create the array and send it.

Comment: I have this hex string ={c88090};  now when I am converting it to bytes which is giving  2's complement. for c8 = -56 so on. And when I am sending singed byte array to Arduino, data is misinterpreted.

Comment: Okay, you can just send the array `new byte[]{(byte)0xc8,(byte)0x80,(byte)0x90}`. The fact that Java treats these values as negative doesn't change anything. The arduino will still get the values c88090

Comment: since `0xff` is int, the `&` auto-promotes the other operand and you don't have to cast the result

Comment: True. I've used casting for clarity since otherwise it's harder to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Since any Java rs232 library is blind to 'signedness', you just send the bytes as-is.

For example, the JSSC library (and iirc RXTX library too) have a method `SerialPort.writeBytes(byte[])`

In Arduino, for received data, you have the choice to interpret signedness as you like, by using `uint8_t` or `int8_t` as appropriately:

```
uint8_t c = Serial.read();
```

Comment: To be precise, `Serial.read()` will return an `int` in the range of 0 .. 0xff,  or -1 for `EOF`/nothing to read

Comment: I recommend using `while(Serial.available())` since after EOF new data can arrive.

Comment: value -1 is not EOF. it is "no data available". same as in Java