# Convert Binary ArrayBuffer/TypedArray Data to Hex String

Tags: javascript, binary-data, arraybuffer, typed-arrays

I would like to get a checksum string from a binary file I'm reading.  The checksum is represented by a `Uint32` value, but how do I convert it to text?  The integer value is `1648231196` and the corresponding text should be "1c033e62" (known via a metadata util).  Note, I am not trying to calculate a checksum, only trying to convert bytes representing the checksum to a string.

Comment: Have you already reviewed the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854166/declaring-an-unsigned-int-in-java

Comment: Thanks, but wrong language :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways who you can read the bytes, [Big-Endian and Little-Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Well, the "checksum" who you provide is a "hex" in Little-Endian. So we can create a buffer and set the number specifying the Little-Endian representation.

```
// Create the Buffer (Uint32 = 4 bytes)
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);

// Create the view to set and read the bytes
const view = new DataView(buffer);

// Set the Uint32 value using the Big-Endian (depends of the type you get), the default is Big-Endian
view.setUint32(0, 1648231196, false);

// Read the uint32 as Little-Endian Convert to hex string
const ans = view.getUint32(0, true).toString(16);

// ans: 1c033e62
```

Always specify the 3rd parameter in [DataView.setUint32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setUint32) and the 2nd in [DataView.getUint32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/setUint32). This defines the format of the "Endian". If you don't set it you can get unexpected results.