# How to create kotlin UInt from java

Tags: java, kotlin

I would like to create an object of:

```
class MyUIntValue(val v: UInt)
```

This works in kotlin:

```
fun main() {
  MyUIntValue(1U)
}
```

But in java code I get an error:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new MyUIntValue(1));
  }
```

```
error: MyUIntValue(int) has private access in MyUIntValue
```

I didn't find in the docs what's the proper way to create a UInt from java?

Comment: There are no unsigned types in Java. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9854205/10514633

Answer (score 3):

`UInt` is implemented as an inline class in Kotlin. Functions that accept inline classes are compiled with "mangled" names so they aren't normally callable from Java. You can disable the name mangling by giving the function an explicit `@JvmName`. I don't think you can do this for a class constructor, so you'd need to declare a separate function that calls through to the constructor.

```kotlin
class MyUIntValue(val v: UInt)

@JvmName("createMyUIntValue")
fun createMyUIntValue(v: UInt) = MyUIntValue(v)
```

According to [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html#calling-from-java-code), this is the recommended way to make `createMyUIntValue` callable from Java code.

Answer (score 1):

For a nullable parameter in kotlin method,disable the name mangling can't fix the type mismatch error, my simple way is:

```
@JvmName(callMeUInt)
fun callMeUInt(v:Int?) = callMe(v?.toUInt())

fun callMe(v:UInt?)
  ...
```

then call in Java:

```
callMeUInt(1);
```

or

```
callMeUInt(null);
```

Kotlin can build the correct object type for nullable Int, but not for nullable UInt.

But be careful,negative values in Java can lead to unexpected results, for example Kotlin will get 4294967293 for -3 in Java.